# No value accessor for form control with name - mat-button-toggle

Tags: angular

Pretty simple problem to fix I assume, although I can't figure out if it's because the mat-button-toggle element may need ControlValueAccessor implementing?

I have a single FormControl which I want to influence through the selection of three toggle buttons.

This doesn't work, and I get the `No value accessor for form control with name` error.

If I replace the buttons with an `<input>` element and put the same `formControlName="cost"` onto it, the form works fine and is updated by the input.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
        <mat-button-toggle-group>
          <mat-button-toggle formControlName="cost" value="<100"><£100</mat-button-toggle>
          <mat-button-toggle formControlName="cost" value="100-250">£100-250</mat-button-toggle>
          <mat-button-toggle formControlName="cost" value=">250">>£250</mat-button-toggle>
        </mat-button-toggle-group>
      </form>
```

```
public form: FormGroup;

constructor(private _propChainService: PropChainService,
            private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
      cost: this._formBuilder.control("")
    });
}
```

Comment: answer is updated

Answer (score 2):

`mat-button-toggle` on its own does not implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface. However the `mat-button-toggle-group` element does. This is the element that need to have the `formControlName` binding on.

```
<mat-button-toggle-group formControlName="cost">
          <mat-button-toggle value="<100"><£100</mat-button-toggle>
          <mat-button-toggle value="100-250">£100-250</mat-button-toggle>
          <mat-button-toggle value=">250">>£250</mat-button-toggle>
        </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

The above works as expected.

Comment: I can't mark this as correct as its my own answer, so there's a 2 day wait. However it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because of missed `import` of material modules

also, check if the `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` are imported in `app.module.ts`

Comment: Where do I need to import the mat-button-toggle and mat-button-toggle-group? They're in my template and they aren't throwing any errors in my IDE saying I'm missing imports. Do I need to add them to my component as well? FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule are in app.module

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without formbuilder:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group
  #group="matButtonToggleGroup"
  [value]="selectedValue"
  (change)="onValueChange(group.value)"
>
  <mat-button-toggle value="option1">
    <£100
  </mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="option2">
    £100-250
  </mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="option3">
    £100-250
  </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>


public selectedValue: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedValue = "option1";
}
  public onValueChange(val: string) {
    this.selectedValue = val;
  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-toggle-group?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're not importing the material modules in your testing module.

So `mat-form-field`, `mat-select`, etc. are just treated as unknown elements by Angular (since you told it to do so by using `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`).

Also you can include `BrowserAnimationsModule` in `app.module.ts` as follows

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  ...,
  imports: [
    ...,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  ...
})
```